Final transistor sought for HF walkie-talkie
I recently discovered an old RadioShack HF 40 channel CB walkie-talkie I own buried under boxes in my cellar. Twenty years ago, I remember experimenting with this unit by attaching a mismatched antenna. Regrettably, the HF 40 channel CB walkie-talkie no longer works properly.
I suspect that the final transistor is faulty. Therefore, I opened the unit and wrote down the transistor code: KD20927B
I have conducted a Google search for this particular transistor and it is not listed anywhere I can discover.
Does anybody know this transistor or its equivalent?

You probably read the transistor code wrong. Almost no transistor is marked with five numerical digits. Ussual numbers are three or four digits.

I removed the shopping part of your question to avoid question closure and signatures are not allowed as they're applied automatically. See the [Tour]. Welcome to EE.SE. Post a photo of the transistor. It might help.

The old RS stuff was usually made in Japan, so I’d expect the transistor to have a designation like 2SCxxxx . The schematics are probably available online.
